# Any opensource C/C++ Libraries/Frameworks for RPC over pipes/internal linux sockets?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, rpc

I am looking for a lightweight opensource library/framework preferably written in C/C++ (it doesn't have to support x languages and should be easy to understand and use.) which can be used to make RPC over internal linux sockets or pipes.
In other words I am looking for an RPC possibility which can be run over some of the linux IPC mechanisms.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [msgpack-rpc](http://msgpack.org/). It's easy and very simple RPC implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the hint but it looks like C/C++ RPC implementation of the msgpack-rpc is not done yet.

Comment: Updated link to C++ msgpack-rpc : https://github.com/jubatus/jubatus-msgpack-rpc/tree/master/cpp

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly lightwieght, but [Dbus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org) is an answer and it's standard on most linux distributions these days.

Comment: As you said, Dbus is not really lightweight. I am looking for something which is less complex.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't want any fancy framework and can handle simple library calls. The linux rpc library should then be sufficient: [See the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rpc), and maybe [this tutorial](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node33.html).

Answer (score 0):

SUN ONC RPC library for Linux is a good solution. Also you can use the **rpcgen** compiler to generate server and client stubs.

All you have to do is to write an .x in the RPCL language an compile it using **rpcgen**.

Here is an example that I have published in github: https://github.com/issamabd/SDL-PPONG

It uses RPC calls to connect two PingPong players over the network.